# Hover effect on div and image is not working in css

Tags: html, css, button, css-selectors

i have a div that contain image [and the image is serve the purpose of button]. I want to make the div or img more user freindly . For that i try to create a border when hover on the it . But its not working . Please see my code

```css
.pa-img, .img-div{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.img-div:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.pa-img:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
  <img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />
</div>
```

If you have any good idea to make this imge more attractive or more effect on hover please help .  I will create a jquery function for the mage click .

But currently user is not able to identify this is a button . They are not clicking the image . That why i try to make hover effect

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it more user-friendly and more aesthetically beautiful, make sure you also get to know a few about Design, and not only coding.

Here's a way of making it more aesthetically beautiful :

```css
.img-div {
    width: 234px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.pa-img, .img-div{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px transparent solid;
}
.img-div:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px;
}
.pa-img:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
<img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />

</div>
```

---

**ALSO -** You can even add rounded borders to make it fit a bit more aesthetically with the PayPal button :

```css
.img-div {
    width: 234px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.pa-img, .img-div{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px transparent solid;
}
.img-div:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px;
}
.pa-img:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
<img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />

</div>
```

IF you want the image also to position a bit to the side and down to work even more like a button, you could do this :

```css
.img-div {
    width: 234px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.pa-img, .img-div{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px transparent solid;
}
.img-div:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px;
}
.pa-img:hover{
    transition:ease-in-out 0.2s;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
<img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />

</div>
```

To make the rounded borders, just add `border-radius: 25px;` (or any value that you prefer) on the `.img-div`

I hope it fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you friend , but the image itself not looking good . And you make shadow in it it look like too bad

Comment: You're welcome, but the image was provided by you, not by me. And also, the inner shadow will give it a look like it's going down, which is what buttons are supposed to look like. Next time be more clear about what you're looking for and then we'll be able to help it better

Comment: Added one more style so it helps you figuring out what fits better for your needs

Answer (score 1):

Use this, the 1px padding is just so the image does not jump around when you add the border.

```
.pa-img{
    padding: 1px;
}
.pa-img:hover{
    padding: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used :hover removed the ::hover placed a transparent border so it wouldn't jump and used a transition so it would move smoothly in and out of hover.

```css
.pa-img, .img-div{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px transparent solid;
}
.img-div:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
    transition:ease-in-out.3s;
}
.pa-img:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
    transition:ease-in-out.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
<img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a transparent border to remove the jumping. With a simple transitions it's less in your face.

```css
.pa-img, .img-div{
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
.img-div:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.pa-img:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div">
  <img class="pa-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/ymCFbTJ/pay-paypal.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes . it is working . Could you please help us to make this image more user friendly . More beautiful visually . We have a form in which we collect the details . And this image and div is place as a submit button . We already made j query function for that . But the the thing user are not able to recognize this is a button

Comment: @abilasher this sounds like entire new question. Instead of adding a border I would recommend to make the image into real HTML and CSS. This will look better on any device as it can scale and makes it easier to understand it's a button

Comment: .pa-img:hover{
    padding: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
 i add this also . but it is not looking good